# How to load an entity from database directly other than cache using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to handle the data access layer. After making changes to an entity and before calling ISession.Update(entity), I would like to get a copy of the entity from database directly, then save it into a audit table as for history tracking. But the problem is, the entity is cached by NHibernate. Seems like there is no way to force NHibernate make a direct call to the database if the entity has been cached?

I know I can make a copy before making any changes to the entity. I am just wondering is it possible to force NHibernate to hit database bypassing the cache? Or what's the best practice to track the history?

Here is my EntityRepository Update method:

```
public void Update(BusinessObject Entity) {

        //I would like to get the existing data from database directly.
        //It doesn't work as the entity is cached
        BusinessObject OldEntity = GetById(Entity.Id);

        using (ITransaction trx = session.BeginTransaction()) {

            session.Update(Entity);

            //Add to history tracking table
            History.Add(OldEntity, Entity, "Update");

            trx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Much appreciated!
Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't hand-craft it like this. There are already NHibernate tools that do that for you - see for example [NHibernate.Envers](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-envers-quick-introduction).

If you really want to implement this on your own, you should go few levels deeper, so that it wouldn't be your repository responsibility to track entities history, as this seems to break [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and is easy to bypass. You should implement it as a listener that listens to update events and save previous version transparently, so that your code stays unaware of auditing - see for example [here](http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/08/31/auditing-with-nhibernate-listeners/).

Comment: Just minutes after I posted the question, I found the IPreXXXXEventListener solution. This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the example link!